# How to customize the front page for each user of specific role?

Tags: 8

For my Drupal 8 website I would like to display for the user after login some page  /related-content/% where % is a contextual filter and needs to be replaced by the current user id. I have downloaded some modules ([Login destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination), User Default Page, Home links) to customize the front page per user role. But I can't figure out how to use the token [current-user:uid] in the right way to display customized front page per user.

Comment: You don't need the argument in the path, it can be the same path for all users, pointing to a View, which gets the then logged in user through a contextual filter.